# Unable to host node & express api on heruko

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, hosting

I have created a simple CRUD API using node, express, and mongoose but when I try to host it on Heroku it fails, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, also add code snippets below.

**Index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: './config.env' });;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyparser.json())

const db = process.env.MONGO_URL;
mongoose.connect(db, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => { console.log('Db Connected');})
    .catch((err) => { console.log('Error while connecting to db' , err); })

const router = require('./route/InventoryRouter');


app.use('/api/inventory', router);

const PORT = process.env.port || 5001;

app.listen(PORT , () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 5001');
})
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node index.js
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v14.x"
  }
}
```

**Heroku error**

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/api/inventory" host....
```

Comment: Should that be `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;`?

Comment: Oh yes, that was a very silly mistake! Thanks